# Mathematica: Building a document with your calculations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a `Mathematica Notebook` with Plot's, Images, Tables and text that I would like to present in a file. I've tried to `append >>>` all the stuff in a `nb` or `m put` that leads to nothing (the plot comes up as -graphic-).

I'm sure a lot of people have done this before! What is the best approach for such a task?

Comment: @David, I know it's a very general question but basically it comes down to getting every calculation sorted out in a document as a report. I found the NotebookWrite command (didn't see it earlier) that might help building up the output of my 'work' notebook in a nice way. Then I'll export that notebook to PDF.

Comment: What file format would you like the output to be in?  What application will it be viewed with? You can format it pretty much as you wish within Mathematica itself and then output it as PDF, RTF or HTML, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just save your current notebook as PDF, using the File menu, perhaps after applying a suitable stylesheet? or is this Mac only functionality?

Comment: Hi, I investigated further and the solution I needed was doing computations and comparisons of data and present that in a document. I now chose to create a second notebook and write all output and findings automatically to it. If I want to keep the results I just save it to PDF. Works great with good quality.